How to make the same request multiple times?
I have to make an API request to an endpoint and see if it returns a specific object. How can I make the same API request multiple times over a 60 second period until it returns that object using playwright? Here's what I tried
await this.page.waitForResponse(
    async resp =>
        resp.url().includes("test") &&
        resp.status() === 200 &&
        ((await resp.json()) as any).libraries.some((lib: { name: string }) => lib.name === libraryName),
        {
            timeout: 60000
        }
);

But I am pretty sure it doesn't make the same request multiple times

Where's the API request? Please share a [mcve].

It looks like you’re on the right track with using waitForResponse, but it might not be the best approach for repeatedly making the same API request. Instead, you can use a loop to make the request multiple times within a 60-second period..
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const endpoint = 'https://your-api-endpoint.com/test';
    const libraryName = 'desiredLibrary';
    const timeout = 60000; // 60 seconds
    const interval = 5000; // 5 seconds interval between requests

    const checkResponse = async () => {
        const response = await page.request.get(endpoint);
        if (response.status() === 200) {
            const data = await response.json();
            return data.libraries.some((lib: { name: string }) => lib.name === libraryName);
        }
        return false;
    };

    const startTime = Date.now();
    let found = false;

    while (Date.now() - startTime < timeout && !found) {
        found = await checkResponse();
        if (!found) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        console.log('Library found!');
    } else {
        console.log('Library not found within the timeout period.');
    }

    await browser.close();
})();

